# Add new row in MYSQL from Comma Separated text in textbox

Tags: php, mysql, textbox, insert

I have a PHP/MYsql question.

I am trying to insert a new row after each comma.

Basically, I want this function:

Let's say we have a textbox with the following text:

Basketball, Tennis, Futbol, Volleyball   --> Submit Button

After the submit button is clicked, I want to Insert a new row in one table after each word.

Basically, I want the outcome in the DB like this

```
id      category
1       Basketball
2       Tennis
3       Futbol
4       Volleyball
```

Anyone can help me with this ?

thanks :)

Comment: You should click the checkmark next to the answer if it is correct

Answer (score 6):

You could just loop through each, and add them individually.

```
$input = "Basketball, Tennis, Futbol, Volleyball";
foreach (explode(',',$input) as $piece)
{
    $piece = mysql_real_escape_string(trim ($piece));
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES($piece)";
    //Run sql
}
```

Comment: It's imperative not to forget `mysql_real_escape_string($piece)` when using it with the real input variable.

Comment: @mario your right, I didn't because I used a variable, but if he is getting it from a form (which he is) then it is imperative.
@halfdan He didn't give a table, columns, etc. Am I suppose to read his mind to format my sql?

Comment: Superb.. Exact answer what i researched.

Comment: @AbijithAjayan If I were doing this today, and you're running PHP 5.6+, look at this instead - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094048/prepared-multiple-insert-mysqli

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one query like so:

```
$Input = explode(',', 'a, b, c, d, e, f, g');
$Query = 'INSERT INTO Table(TableColumn) VALUES';

foreach ($Input as $Entry)
{
    $Query .= '("' . $Entry . '"), ';
}

$Query = substr_replace($Query, '', -2);

mysql_query($Query);
```

The outputted query will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table(TableColumn) VALUES("a"), ("b"), ("c"), ("d"), ("e"), ("f"), ("g")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ??

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

Just grab the values from the super global GET/POST/REQUEST array:

```
$categories = $_REQUEST['categories'];
```

Make them seperate values:

```
$categories = explode(",", $categories);
```

For each value in the array create a SQL statement and execute it.

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $category = trim($category); // Remove possible whitespace
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (category) VALUES ('%s')";
    $sql = sprintf($sql, mysql_real_escape_string($category));
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest code:

```
$Input = explode(',', 'a, b, c, d, e, f, g');
if($Input){
    echo('INSERT INTO Table(TableColumn) VALUES ("'.
      implode('"),("',$Input).'")');
}
```

However you would need to have your $Input escaped.