# How to insert comma separated string into MySQL table while each part in new row?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, explode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add new row in MYSQL from Comma Separated text in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690250/add-new-row-in-mysql-from-comma-separated-text-in-textbox)
>   [Insert comma separated records in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134967/insert-comma-separated-records-in-table)

```
$words = 'word1,word2,word3';
```

How do i get this data into following structure:

MySQL table:

```
id    value
 1    word1
 2    word2
 3    word3
```

What i am thinking of:

```
$separated = explode(",",$words);
//do some kind of loop
INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES ('$something');
```

I guess i suck at loops :/

Thanks

Comment: If you know you need a loop, write one and see what happens. If it doesn't work show us what you've got and we can help you with it. But *at least try*.

Comment: do the freakin loop. If you `suck at loops` open freakin manual at loop page, read, use it and you gonna be loop master

Comment: Seems like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8135264/1073631

Answer (score 2):

```
$wordArray = explode(",", $words);

$stmt = "INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('" . implode("'), ('", $wordArray) . "')";
```

This will produce:

```
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('word1'), ('word2'), ('word3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple loop, as such:

```
foreach($separated as $seperate){
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES ('$seperate')";
}
```

Comment: This is inefficient; you should send them in one statement. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635818/multiple-insert-statements-vs-single-insert-with-multiple-values).

Comment: Yep, something quick to whip up

Comment: Don't use `@` to suppress errors. It makes debugging difficult.

Comment: @JohnConde not sure why the post was edited to add @. also added quotes...

Comment: @njk it's not always possible to use a single statement only added as a stub