# Prepared multiple Insert mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Please read the full question before closing it :)
Im looking for a prepared statement with **mysqli** (Important, not PDO, because I can't use it and can't transfer some PDO code to mysqli.), where i can insert on long query with a lot of values (about 2000). But the query has to be prepared.

---

So i started like that:

```
$array = array("a1", "a2", "a3","a5", "a7", "a5","a9", "a32", "a3", "a4"); 
// AND SO ON UP TO 2000
$type = "s";
$end = count($array);

$query = "INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES (?)";
for ($i = 0; $i <= $end - 1; $i++) 
{
    $query  .= ", (?)";
    $type   .= "s";
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
$stmt->bind_param("$type", /* PROBLEM */); // HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

---

But now my problem, how can I bind the variables in "bind_param" dynamicaly?
Please dont show me anything like for-loops on "execute", because this is too sloww for 2000 inserts :).

I mean something like

```
$allvalues = "";
foreach ($array as $value) 
{
    $allvalues .= "$value ";
}
$stmt->bind_param("$type", $allvalues);
```

But of course, I cant bind that.

Comment: "(Important, not PDO, because I can't use it and can't transfer some PDO code to mysqli.)"-- PDO is cross database thats why most people choose it...

Comment: Ok, but why should I use different databases? I only need mysql, I tested PDO vs mysqli and mysqli was **always** faster, so no need of PDO.

Comment: @CopyDevil where is your proof to that staement?

Comment: I tested it with microtime(), but if that was only a coincidence, and it is not like that, please show me something else, an example or something, it would help me a lot :) Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`call_user_func_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to call the function using an array.

Or just pass all of the variables through to execute, then you do not even need to use `bind_param`

Comment: @CopyDevil you might want to modify your code to work in smaller chunks, I'll bet a dollar that passing 2000 arguments to a function will eventually cause a... \*sunglasses\* Stack Overflow. *YYYEEEEEEAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHHHH* \*guitar riff\*

Comment: @Sammitch, that was the best moment I've seen on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I have just spent ages trying to find a simple and elegant solution to exactly this problem and found something perfect (works in php5.6 and above).

```
$array = array("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6"); 

$type = str_repeat("s", 6);

$query = "INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES (?)" . str_repeat(", (?)", 6);

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
$stmt->bind_param($type, ...$array);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

The ...$array thing is called a [splat operator](https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator). I had a problem when I tried inserting to more than one row - because it didn't give the values in the correct order - so just had to create one single array that included all the rows.